# Подозрительно похожие вопросы от подозрительно похожих участников

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Есть [вопрос 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212795/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85) [вопрос 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212790/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE) и [вопрос 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212787/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0). По общему количеству три участника задало три вопроса. Но мне кажется это было сделано одним и тем же человеком. Товарищ [Николай Семенов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/333174/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)
имеет брата близнеца [Semenov Nilolay](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373855/semenov-nilolay) и подозрительно похожий товарищ [Эрнан Кортес](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373854/%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81). Лексика заданных вопросов и их принцип построения идентичен, метки тоже. Я не знаю, может имеет смысл объединить этих господ каким-то образом или какие-то еще применить действия :)

### UPDATE

Еще один "[родственник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373853/sem)" и [его вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212785/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-sys-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1) общими усилиями найденный :)

Comment: [ещё один аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212785/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, этого я не учёл)) совсем почти неочевидно)

Comment: При такой длине текста может быть просто копипаст заданий из одной методички, хотя двое с одинаковыми именами скорее против этой версии.

Comment: насколько я знаю такой обход категорически запрещен и это наказуемо. по моему таких человечков модераторы должны забанить на время, чтобы подумали. хотя я не знаю, как здесь лучше

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы как представитель администрации что скажете по поводу предыдущего коммента?) есть какие-то меры противодействия?

Comment: @alex9127, если аккаунты созданы случайно, то стараемся объединять, а не банить. Если созданы ради накрутки, то банить, конечно. Либо после предупреждения, либо сразу - по обстоятельствам.